# Ionic: Displaying web content on iOS device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have problem with Ionic app on iPad.
When I open link what is coded in template:

```
<a ng-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions" target="_self"
```

Then I get full screen browser view what even overlay native top bar - see screanshot:

[image]

How to get back button displayed with proper header bar in that view?
It is possible to easy display pdf/doc files?

Comment: Downvoter maybe some comment and then voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the inappbrowser plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

This plugin with the option `location=yes` displays a location bar with a close button.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following this steps gave me right web content handling (even pdf/odt) in Ionic:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Add reference `ngCordova` to `app.js` like:

```
angular.module('starter', [
'ionic',
'restangular',
'ngCordova',
```

Add ngCordova source to `index.html`:

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

Then change link from:

```
<a ng-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions" target="_self"> link </a>
```

to link with display properties (see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

```
<a ng-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions" 
    onclick="window.open(this.href,
                        '_blank',
                        'location=yes,toolbarposition=top,closebuttoncaption=BACK');
             return false;"
>Link</a>
```

Or use a function in controller bound to html (may not work with redirection as nice as example above):

```
 <button type="button" class="item" ng-click="openBrowser()">OPEN BROWSER</button>

 var options = {
                location: 'yes',
                closebuttoncaption: 'BACK',
                toolbarposition: 'top'
            };

            $scope.openBrowser = function () {
                $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://google.com', '_self', options)

                    .then(function (event) {
                        // success
                    })

                    .catch(function (event) {
                        // error
                    });
            };
```

Solution with tricky usage `this.href` of fund here https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/#comment-2175484195